# PHP : Sending Boundary Values in Curl Headers

Tags: php, curl

I want to send the below data in curl headers.

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------28854217951032752725060171
```

I used below code , but it seems not to work

```
$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/525.13 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/0.A.B.C Safari/525.13");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=---------------------------28854217951032752725060171'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEJAR, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_COOKIEFILE, "cookie.txt");
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $fields_string);
$result = curl_exec($ch); 
$last = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_EFFECTIVE_URL);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
return array($result,$last,$info);
curl_close($ch);
```

What is the correct way to send the boundary value.
P.s : 28854217951032752725060171 is constant value.

Comment: Why does it need to be `multipart/form-data`? Are you uploading a file?

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to send this value manually. Curl will handle this by itself.

**Edit:**

`CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` can accept array, and it will attach the `Content-Type` as well as the needed boundaries automatically. Here is [quote](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) from PHP documentation:

> *If value is an array, the Content-Type header will be set to
>   multipart/form-data. As of PHP 5.2.0, value must be an array if files
>   are passed to this option with the @ prefix.*

For example:

```
$data = array(
    'name' => 'Foo',
    'file' => '@/absolute/path/to/some/file'
);
```

Comment: how to mention i am sending multipart/form-data; ?

Comment: @Vishnu Simbu - The data is passed to curl engine via CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS - you can pass to it an array which holds absolute paths to the files that you want to send.

Comment: hey $fields is an string value,How to mention array in it ?